# Android SQLite Query with WHERE not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite, where-clause, sqliteopenhelper

Hey guys I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time now but I can't seem to get it solved.

I try to query a row from my SQLite database in my Android App and I have some odd behavior.

I have the following unit test:

```
public class DatabaseTest extends AndroidTestCase {
    ...
    public void testSaveMeeting() {
        Meeting meeting = new Meeting(1, MeetingStatus.ONGOING);
        MeetingDataSource mds = new MeetingDataSource(getContext());

        long meetingId = mds.save(meeting);
        assertEquals(meeting, mds.getById(meetingId));
    }
}
```

Here I try to save my model object `meeting` to the database with my database mapper. The following snippet is my model `Meeting` which stores the data which should be saved to the database:

```
public class Meeting {
    private long id;
    private MeetingStatus meetingStatus;

    public Meeting() {}

    public Meeting(long meetingId, MeetingStatus meetingStatus) {
        this.id = meetingId;
        this.meetingStatus = meetingStatus;
    }

    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public void setMeetingStatus(MeetingStatus meetingStatus) { this.meetingStatus = meetingStatus; }
    public MeetingStatus getMeetingStatus() { return meetingStatus; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Meeting meeting = (Meeting) o;

        return id == meeting.id && meetingStatus == meeting.meetingStatus;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}
}
```

And my MeetingDataSource is a mapper class with which I try to map my model objects to the database and vice versa. This class looks like the following:

```
public class MeetingDataSource extends DataSource<Meeting> {
    private static String REQUEST_TABLE_NAME = DatabaseContract.MeetingTable.TABLE_NAME;

    private static String[] ALL_COLUMNS = {
            DatabaseContract.MeetingTable._ID,
            DatabaseContract.MeetingTable.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS
    };

    public MeetingDataSource(Context context) { super(context); }

    @Override
    public Meeting cursorToObject(Cursor cursor) {
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
            meeting.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
            meeting.setMeetingStatus(MeetingStatus.valueOfLabel(cursor.getString(1)));

            return meeting;
        }
        return null;
    }

@Override
    protected ContentValues objectToContentValues(Meeting meeting) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseContract.MeetingTable._ID, meeting.getId());
        values.put(DatabaseContract.MeetingTable.COLUMN_NAME_STATUS, meeting.getMeetingStatus().getLabel());
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public Meeting getById(long id) {
        try {
            openReadConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String where = DatabaseContract.MeetingTable._ID + " = ?";
        String[] whereValues = { String.valueOf(id) };

        // I think this is the part where my Problem is.
        Cursor cursor = database.query(
                REQUEST_TABLE_NAME,
                ALL_COLUMNS,
                where,
                whereValues,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        Meeting meeting = cursorToObject(cursor);

        closeConnection();
        return meeting;
    }

    @Override
    public long save(Meeting meeting) {
        try {
            openWriteConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long rowId = database.insert(REQUEST_TABLE_NAME, null, objectToContentValues(meeting));

        closeConnection();
        return rowId;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Meeting meeting) {...}

    @Override
    public List<Meeting> getAll() {...}
}
```

This class extends the following adapter `DataSource`. This is a wrapper for the `SQLiteOpenHelper` which is used to create the database itself:

```
public abstract class DataSource<DatabaseTableType> {
    protected Context context;
    protected SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    public DataSource(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    protected void openReadConnection() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
    protected void openWriteConnection() throws SQLException { database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); }
    protected void closeConnection() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    protected abstract DatabaseTableType cursorToObject(Cursor cursor);
    protected abstract ContentValues objectToContentValues(DatabaseTableType object);

    public abstract DatabaseTableType getById(long id);
    public abstract List<DatabaseTableType> getAll();

    public abstract long save(DatabaseTableType object);
    public abstract void update(DatabaseTableType object);
}
```

Now here is the odd part:
When I add the where statement and arguments in my `MeetingDataSource` in the method `getById` like above my assertEquals in the test fails, because my cursor is empty and therefore the return value of `cursorToObject`
But if I leave it out like this:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(
    REQUEST_TABLE_NAME,
    ALL_COLUMNS,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

my test suceeds, which leads me to believe that the correct Object has been generated by `cursorToObject`.
I also tried the `rawQuery`:

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + REQUEST_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE _id = ?", whereValues);
```

which returns also `null`. Whereas

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + REQUEST_TABLE_NAME, null);
```

returns the right `Meeting` and also lets my test pass.

I'm very thankful for any answers :)

**EDIT 1**

It migth be helpful to see how I defined my table and what my `SQLiteOpenHelper` does.

Here is my DatabaseHelper which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create and tear down my database when it's accessed the first time:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "lma.db";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.AttendanceStatusTable.SETUP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.MeetingStatusTable.SETUP_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.MeetingTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.AttendanceTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.LocationTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.ContactPositionTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.RouteTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.StepTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.WarningTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.RoutesToWarningsTable.CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.RoutesToStepsTable.CREATE_TABLE);

        Log.i(TAG, "Database created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.RoutesToStepsTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.RoutesToWarningsTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.WarningTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.StepTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.RouteTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.ContactPositionTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.LocationTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.AttendanceTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.MeetingTable.DROP_TABLE);

        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.MeetingStatusTable.DROP_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.AttendanceStatusTable.DROP_TABLE);

        Log.i(TAG, "Database dropped");

        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

In my DatabaseContract I define all SQL-statements to create my tables. It also defines my column and table names:

```
public final class DatabaseContract {
    private static final String INT_TYPE = " INTEGER";
    private static final String VARCHAR_TYPE = " VARCHAR(25)";

    private static final String COMMA = ", ";

    private static final String DROP_TABLE_STATEMENT = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
    private static final String PRIMARY_KEY = " PRIMARY KEY";
    private static final String NOT_NULL = " NOT NULL";

    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class
    public DatabaseContract() {}

    // Enum Types
    ...
    public static abstract class MeetingStatusTable implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "meeting_statuses";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TYPE = "type";

        public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_NAME_TYPE + VARCHAR_TYPE + PRIMARY_KEY + ");";
        public static final String INSERT_DATA = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_NAME_TYPE + ") " + "VALUES (\"NEW\"), (\"ONGOING\"), (\"TERMINATED\"), (\"COMPLETED\");";

        public static final String SETUP_TABLE = CREATE_TABLE + INSERT_DATA;
        public static final String DROP_TABLE = DROP_TABLE_STATEMENT + TABLE_NAME + ";";
    }

    // Data Tables
    public static abstract class MeetingTable implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "meetings";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_STATUS = "status";

        public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                _ID + INT_TYPE + PRIMARY_KEY + NOT_NULL + COMMA +
                COLUMN_NAME_STATUS + VARCHAR_TYPE + NOT_NULL + COMMA +
                " FOREIGN KEY (" + COLUMN_NAME_STATUS + ") REFERENCES " + MeetingStatusTable.TABLE_NAME + " (" + MeetingStatusTable.COLUMN_NAME_TYPE + ")" +
                " );";

        public static final String DROP_TABLE = DROP_TABLE_STATEMENT + TABLE_NAME + ";";
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Well in the comments I got asked whether my `save` method in my `MeetingDataSource` actually returns the correct value, and this isn't the case. With this edit I added the Code of my save method in my `MeetingDataSource` which seems to be the actual troublemaker.

Comment: Table definition? What is the actual value returned by `save`?

Comment: @CL. I edited my Post for table definition. Well that's a good question actually I will check with an additional assert.

Comment: @CL. There seems to be the problem: When I have the following assertion in my code: assertEquals(meeting.getId(), meetingId); I get: `AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<-1>` I will post the my code of the save method also.

Comment: I don't know if this explains the problem, but is there a reason you do not use AUTOINCREMENT on the _id column of MeetingTable?

Comment: @Karakuri Yes that is intentional this id has to be unique across the whole system (which includes the serverside) :)

Comment: @Karakuri An INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column does not need AUTOINCREMENT to be autoincrementing; AUTOINCREMENT just prevents reusing deleted IDs. ([doc](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html))

Comment: Remove the `try`/`catch`; you cannot handle these errors by ignoring them.

Comment: Replace `insert` with `insertOrThrow` to get a useful error message.

Comment: @CL. I added my own answer I hope it is understandable. I removed the try/catch like you said (ty for the tip) and I will have a look at insertOrThrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to the comments below my question I was able to figure out what was going wrong. Since I am testing my databse mappers I had the call

```
mockContext.deleteDatabase(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_NAME);
```

in my setUp() method for my tests to make sure my database was empty before my tests. But when I realised that setUp() is executed before every test I removed this line. Since I didn't reinstall my app after every test run the database was not cleaned and therefor the insert tried to insert data which was already in the database, therefor returning -1 as index since the primary key in my table has to be unique.